# Printing out a list with streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to print out a list which represents rows from the database
At the moment when I try to print the list with a stream, it prints out what I think is the location of the item?

This is what i see as output:

BLL.Teacher@6d9c638

BLL.Teacher@7dc5e7b4

Process finished with exit code 0

Each of these outputs is 1 row in the database, because when i add another, an extra output adds to it.

This the code which give above output:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Controller.getAlleTeachers()
                .stream()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

When I add a map function to it, then it gives the correct output.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Controller.getAlleTeachers()
                .stream()
                .map(m->m.getFirstName())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

So above code does output the first names of the rows in the database
Also when i print out the list using foreach, the output is correct:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        for (Teacher t: Controller.getAlleTeachers()
             ) {
            System.out.println(t.getFirstName() + " " +
                               t.getLastName() + " " +
                               t.getCourse() + " " +
                               t.getStartDate());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

So this last part of code also output all the correct information,
So I know the problem isn't with connecting to db or accessing the data, or even the methods passing the data. So I thought it must've been something with the stream? How come I get such a strange output when using streams?

Comment: If @efekctive statement is true, then override your toString method. Something like: return fName + " " + lName + ...

Comment: Your question had nothing to do with MySQL or JDBC, so I have removed those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you didn't override toString() method in Teacher class. **BLL.Teacher@6d9c638** and **BLL.Teacher@7dc5e7b4** - these are references for objects(Default toString() output). Try to override toString() method.

Comment: This did the trick, tnx

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the lambda expression uses the toString() of the object, the for each loop uses the values of the fields. You can put

```
System.out.println(t.getFirstName() + " " +
                               t.getLastName() + " " +
                               t.getCourse() + " " +
                               t.getStartDate());
```

inside the lambda expression

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to Print an instance of teacher; toString() method of that object gets called. Since you haven't overriden toString() you get the default toString() gets printed. BLL.Teacher@6d9c638

And If i recall correctly that hexdecimal value that comes after @ is the memory location of the object

Long story short try to implement 
Public String toString(){ return this.name +.... rest of field ;}
On the teacher object